# Python Rank values from closest to target

Tags: python

I have a problem. In my code I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {}
dict['A'] = {'slope': -51, 'score': 0}
dict['B'] = {'slope': 12, 'score': 0}
dict['C'] = {'slope': -4, 'score': 0}
dict['D'] = {'slope': -31, 'score': 0}
target = -21
```

The dictionary isn't sorted!
Now what I am trying to do is, give each item in the `dict` a score (1 to 4).
The dict closest to the `target` gets 4 points, the next one 3 points, etc.

First I thought I iterate over the dict values, but then I realised that I don't know which if there are values closer than the current one, so I can't keep the score about that.

In the end, it needs to look like this:

```
{'A': {'slope': -51, 'score': 2}, 'B': {'slope': 12, 'score': 1}, 'C': {'slope': -4, 'score': 3}, 'D': {'slope': -31, 'score': 4}}
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Why is -51 -> 2 and -4 -> 3? Also, don't name your variable *dict* as you're shadowing builtin name.

Comment: @CristiFati because -31 is closest to -21, -4 is second closest to -21, -51 is third closest to -21 and 12 is farthest from -21. More Points are assigned if you are closer.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish: Thx, I didn't carefully read the question, it's in reversed order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the items of the dictionary by distance from the target in descending order. Then, the index of the item plus one is the number of points it should get:

```py
sorted_items = sorted(state.items(),
    key=lambda x: abs(x[1]['slope'] - target), reverse=True)

for idx, (key, _) in enumerate(sorted_items, start=1):
    state[key]['score'] = idx
    
print(state)
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 'A': {'slope': -51, 'score': 2},
 'B': {'slope': 12, 'score': 1},
 'C': {'slope': -4, 'score': 3},
 'D': {'slope': -31, 'score': 4}
}
```

I've renamed `dict` to `state` here, because `dict` is the name of a Python builtin.

Comment: I like your approach of sorting in reverse and using `enumerate()` for scores better!

Answer (score 2):

First, don't call your dictionaries `dict`, because `dict` is the name of the builtin dictionary class.

```
d = {}
d['A'] = {'slope': -51, 'score': 0}
d['B'] = {'slope': 12, 'score': 0}
d['C'] = {'slope': -4, 'score': 0}
d['D'] = {'slope': -31, 'score': 0}
target = -21
```

Now, you can sort the keys of the dict based on how far the `slope` value is from `target`:

```
>>> sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: abs(d[k]['slope'] - target))
['D', 'C', 'A', 'B']
```

Then, you can assign scores:

```
num_keys = len(sorted_keys)
for key, score in zip(sorted_keys, range(num_keys, 0, -1)):
    d[key]['score'] = score
```

Which gives you this `d`:

```
{'A': {'slope': -51, 'score': 2},
 'B': {'slope': 12, 'score': 1},
 'C': {'slope': -4, 'score': 3},
 'D': {'slope': -31, 'score': 4}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the *values* of the dict.

Note: don't call your dict like that, since it is the name of a native function.

```
d = {
  'A': {'slope': -51, 'score': 0},
  'B': {'slope': 12, 'score': 0},
  'C': {'slope': -4, 'score': 0},
  'D': {'slope': -31, 'score': 0}
}
target = -21

for i, item in enumerate(sorted(d.values(), key=lambda x: abs(target - x["slope"]),
                                            reverse=True), 1):
    item["score"] = i

print(d)
```